# vue-router path-to-regexp does not match optional route path parameter group

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

### Introduction

I'm working with the official [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) of vue.js.

I'm currently trying to get a route to match using [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html). Since vue-router uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) under the hood, one can use regex in a route path as described [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns). You can find an example of the vue-router using this feature [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js).

#### The Problem

This is my route:

```
{
    path: '/a/:id/(r/:generic1/)?s/:name/a'
}
```

Here some examples that DO work:

```
'/a/1234/s/Foo/a' // => {0: undefined, id: "1234", name: "Foo"}
'/a/23456/s/Bar/a' // => {0: undefined, id: "23456", name: "Bar"}
```

Here some examples that DO NOT work, but SHOULD:

```
'/a/1234/r/Bar/s/Foo/a' // => {id: "1234", generic1: "Bar", name: "Foo"}
'/a/23456/r/Baz/s/Goo/a' // => {id: "1234", generic1: "Baz", name: "Goo"}
```

.. what am I doing wrong here? One of the examples states the following:

> make part of the path optional by wrapping with parens and add "?" *[sic]*

I think these paths should match the given route.

Comment: Your second outputs seem right to me. What's expected?

Comment: @revo I might have been to unclear. the problem is that the route doesn't match. the screen stays white, no site is loaded. if I use the first routes, my page is displayed, if I use the second ones, it isn't. the output you see is that what I would expect to be matched

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/106#issuecomment-302869563) you can't put params inside the regexp area. The workaround should be something like [this](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/106#issuecomment-302873640).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/106#issuecomment-302869563), you can't put params inside the regexp area.

I think you can do something like this `/a/:id/r?/:generic1?/s/:name/a` this should match all of your examples and also preserves the *generic1* param.

I verified this solution with the [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/).

Comment: I changed it accordingly but it still doesn't work. If I dump $route It shows [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mbv38f8xbv70fie/chrome_2018-03-07_18-56-56.png). I'm not sure what I am missing here. (btw, the path doesn't end with `/a` because this is the next higher root path, it's children end with `/a`, `b` and `c` and so on. a redirect is setup to forward the user to `/a` anyways)

Comment: i see you updated your pattern. .. i tried it again, still doesn't work :/

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why was a ? in front of the s in the path.. can you show me your current path?

Comment: I'm currently have the following route defined: `'/a/:id/r?/:generic1?/s/:name'` with a redirect to `'/a/:id/r?/:generic1?/s/:name/a'`. using this route schema makes the 'working examples' from the question not work anymore. also, accessing a route like `/a/12997/r/Aura/s/Echo` also doesn't work, nor does it redirect to `../a`.

Comment: I've been trying the express route tester you linked and managed to build something which works with all my examples: `/a/:id/([r]/)?:generic1?/?s/:name`. but If I copy into my solution, the path still doesn't match. .. why?

Comment: I can solve this by using an alias for now.. although the redirects are somewhat not working right now. I'd really like this to work without an alias, this makes everything more complex